# Glassfish logging not working as expected

Tags: logging, glassfish, java.util.logging

I setup my logger using:

`private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Bar.class.getName());`

where `Bar` has structure: `de.foo.aip.web.action.Bar`

Now in my glassfish, I set the level: 
`de.foo.aip` to Level `WARNING`. I thought it would apply to my `Bar` class.
However this does not apply. When I set the full name

`de.foo.aip.web.action.Bar` to `WARNING`

it works. But I want to set the log-level on the root `de.foo.aip`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your classes has to forcefully create and pin logger named `de.foo.aip` in order for the child logger `de.foo.aip.web.action.Bar` to inherit the level.

Change your code to:

```
private static final Object PIN = Logger.getLogger("de.foo.aip");
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Bar.class.getName());
```

which will force create the root logger you want to control via the `logging.properties`.